# Keras Generator keeps looping for no reason

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a keras generator

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=360,
                                       horizontal_flip=True,
                                       vertical_flip=True,
                                       validation_split=0.15,
                                       preprocessing_function=preprocess_image, 
                                       rescale=1 / 128.)

left_test_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df_test_left, 
                                                    directory = test_images_path,
                                                    x_col="pic_id",
                                                    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                                    batch_size=1,
                                                    shuffle=False, 
                                                    class_mode=None, seed=SEED)
```

the length of left_test_generator is 500

but when if i run this

```
for image_count, image in enumerate(right_test_generator):
    print(image_count)
```

this will print image_count which is greater than 8000.
What is going on here? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how generators work, internally they have an infinite loop that produces batches of data, the `__len__` method is just for reference to be aware of how many calls to the generator are required to reach one epoch.

So if you want to get a specific number of samples from the generator, you should not iterate on it like that, use a for loop with a specific number of iterations.